Stuck at installing Mediapipe on an Linux EC2 instance
I'm trying to deploy a streamlit application which basically is a object detection project built using Mediapipe. I managed to clone my git repo into the instance and install all packages except Mediapipe, its alway stuck at downloading torch as
  Downloading torch-2.2.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (755.5 MB)
     |█████████████▎                  | 314.2 MB 643 bytes/s eta 7 days, 22:29:56

I'm trying this method so far, pls help
python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed mediapipe

I faced the same issue.
what I did is, downgrade the mediapipe version and then it completed without an error.
version I used: pip install mediapipe==0.10.9
I used this image:amazon/ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-amd64-server (may be others will work but this works for me)

please consider formatting code snippets by enclosing them into Backtics and code blocks by enclosing them into triple backtics for better raedability
